# Qml Text Size based on Container

Tags: qt, text, label, qml

I am using Qt Quick to develop an app (Qt 5.8).  I have text that appears in multiple places so I created a component to use to display the text.  The areas the text can vary in placement and size.  How can I adjust my text so that the data displays in 1 line horizontally and all text is the same size if I simply want to display the following?

FLAPS 1
GEAR DOWN
TRIM -1.0

I used Text and was able to get close, however since GEAR DOWN has more characters the text was smaller, than flaps and trim.  So I moved on to using Label.  Can someone provide better insight on how to have text size based on its container's width or height?

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    id: windowRoot
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Rectangle{
        height: windowRoot.height * .80
        width: windowRoot.width * .80
        color: "green"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        Rectangle {
            id: rect1
            opacity: .5
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.left: parent.left
            color: "lime"
            border.color: "orange"
            height: parent.height * 1/2
            width: parent.width * 1/2
            TextHolder {
                anchors.top: parent.top
                anchors.left: parent.left
                width: parent.width * 1/4
                height: parent.height
            }
        }
        Rectangle {
            id: rect2
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.left: rect1.right
            color: "yellow"
            border.color: "blue"
            height: parent.height * 1/2
            width: parent.width * 1/2
        }
        Rectangle {
            id: rect3
            anchors.top: rect1.bottom
            anchors.left: parent.left
            color: "pink"
            border.color: "red"
            height: parent.height * 1/2
            width: parent.width * 1/2
            TextHolder {
                anchors.top: parent.top
                anchors.left: parent.left
                width: parent.width * 1/4
                height: parent.height * 1/2
            }
        }
        Rectangle {
            id: rect4
            anchors.top: rect2.bottom
            anchors.left: rect3.right
            color: "orange"
            border.color: "lime"
            height: parent.height * 1/2
            width: parent.width * 1/2
            TextHolder {
                anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                height: parent.height * 1/4
                width: parent.width * 1/4
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            }
        }
    }
}
```

TextHolder.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1

Rectangle {
    color: "purple"
    border.color: "steelblue"
    border.width: 3
    property color colorOfText: "white"
    property real textSize: 48
    Item {
        id: inputs
        property int flapHndl: 1
        property int gearHndl: 1
        property real trim: -1.0
    }

    clip: true

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.top: parent.top
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        spacing: 5

        Label {
            id: flapLabel
            text: "FLAPS " + inputs.flapHndl
            color: colorOfText
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            font.pixelSize: textSize
            fontSizeMode: Text.HorizontalFit
            Layout.fillWidth: true
        }

        Label {
            id: gearLabel
            text: {
                if (inputs.gearHndl === 1)
                    return "GEAR DOWN"
                else
                    return "GEAR UP"
            }
            color: colorOfText
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            font.pixelSize: textSize
            fontSizeMode: Text.HorizontalFit
            Layout.fillWidth: true
        }

        Label {
            id: trimLabel
            text: "TRIM " + inputs.trim.toFixed(1)
            color: colorOfText
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            font.pixelSize: textSize
            fontSizeMode: Text.HorizontalFit
            Layout.fillWidth: true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can someone provide better insight on how to have text size based on
> its container's width or height?

For evaluating the text width and height we can definitely use QML type [TextMetrics](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textmetrics.html) and having the metrics we can then attempt to fit the text in. If the text still won't fit we can then try to adjust the font size. For that, some logic might need to be implemented with JavaScript. So, the below code is an example of the "feedback" type of solution.

```
Rectangle {
   property string textToShow
   property int widthLimit: 400

   onTextToShowChanged: {
      while (txtMeter.width > widthLimit) {
         txtMeter.font.pixelSize --;
      }
   }

   TextMetrics {
      id: txtMeter
      font.family: "Courier"
      font.pixelSize: 25
      text: textToShow
   }

   Text {
      font: txtMeter.font
      text: textToShow
   }
}
```

P.S. This is just a sketchy idea and your actual implementation may differ

Comment: For anyone using this method, I found that txtMeter.width can update AFTER onTextToShowChanged is invoked.  You might need to instead put that code into a trigger called onTextChanged inside of the TextMetrics block instead to ensure things are updated in the necessary order

Comment: @KyleL Make one more answer?

Answer (score 2):

There is ***fontSizeMode*** property of **Text**

```
Text {
            id: goToParentFolderText
            anchors.fill: parent
            font.family: fontAwesomeSolid.name
            text: "\uf060"
            fontSizeMode: Text.Fit
            font.pointSize: 100
            color: Material.accent
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get @Alexander V's answer to work, with a minor change.  The outer textToShow property was processing its update before the TextMetrics block was updated (which caused the width calculation to be incorrect).  You can fix this issue by triggering onTextChanged inside the TextMetrics blocks instead.

```
Rectangle {
   property string textToShow
   property int widthLimit: 400

   TextMetrics {
      id: txtMeter
      font.family: "Courier"
      font.pixelSize: 25
      text: textToShow

      onTextChanged: {
         while (txtMeter.width > widthLimit) {
            txtMeter.font.pixelSize --;
         }
      }
   }

   Text {
      font: txtMeter.font
      text: textToShow
   }
}
```